# Django multiple model query in view

Tags: django

I've made a query set as like below to add multiple model query passes to view.

```
class ProjectListView(ListView):
    model = Projects
    template_name = 'project.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        group_name = 'example'
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(group__name__contains=group_name)
        object_list['group_details'] = Group.objects.all()
        return object_list
```

But it shows `'QuerySet' object does not support item assignment`. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do what your trying to do.

You should just include the group details in the context data through `get_context_data`